# PHP SOAP Webservice authentication

Tags: php, web-services, symfony, soap

First, just to be clear with you, I'm a beginner with Symfony 2 so I want to apologize for my mistakes in the futur.

I'm looking for some help about my issue. Reading the SensionLab documentation about Symfony (2.7 version), I've tried to implement a login form with a webservice user provider. This WS is linked to a database containing all data's user.

Today, when I try an authentication :

- with wrong credentials, I'm redirect to my login form with an error
  message (It's ok).
- with right credentials, I'm redirect to my login form too

Here my code where I try an authentication with my WS :

```
public function authenticate(TokenInterface $token)
{
    if (!$this->supports($token)) {
        return new AuthenticationException('Token error');
    }
    //WebService
    $client = new \Soapclient('URL', array('trace' => 1, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));

    $response = $client->__call('authenticationFunction', array("login" => md5($token->getAttribute("username")), "password" => md5($token->getAttribute("password"))));

    if ($response->id != 0) {
        $user = $this->provider->createUser($token->getAttributes(), array(new Role('ROLE_USER')));
        $token->setUser($user);
        $token->setAuthenticated(true);
    } else {
        $token->setAuthenticated(false);
    }
    return $token;
}
```

And my security.yml file :

```
security:
    encoders:
        SQLI\UserBundle\Security\User\WebServiceUser: plaintext


    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        webservice:
            id: web_service.security.user.provider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/login$
            security: false

        area_secured:
            pattern:    ^/
            web_service: true
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
                default_target_path: /
                provider: webservice

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

My function work and return an id != 0 but, for some test I have replaced :

```
if ($response->id != 0) 
///With
if(true)
```

And it's work and we can signin to my app with any credentials (Bad one too).

So it's really weird and I need some help to understand how to correct this bug.

Thanks in advance.